# Cool exercise in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

(correct version)Consider in $R^n$ the Lebesgue measure. Consider a  mapping $A : {R}^{n} \times {R}^{n} \rightarrow {R}^{n}$  satisfying the following conditions:

i) the mapping $x \rightarrow  A(x , \theta)$ is measurable for all $\theta \in {R}^n$ and

ii) the mapping $\theta \rightarrow  A(x , \theta)$ is continuous for a.e $x \in {R}^n$ .

Show that the composed mapping $x \rightarrow A(x,g(x))$ is measurable whenever $g$ is a measurable function.

I don't know how to begin... Someone can give me a hint? 
Thanks (my english is terrible, sorry)

Comment: What do $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have to do with the problem?

Comment: Ops... i make a mistake, ignore the constants

Comment: If you cannot do it (right away) for all measurable $g$, try to do it first for some simpler $g$.

Comment: If i can prove to simple functions , i dont know how to use this to show the general case (the case of the question )...

Comment: The conditions are called Carathéodory conditions. - If you can show the statement for simple functions, use ii) and the fact that every measurable function can be written as a pointwise limit of simple functions.